# Nilpotency of linear transformations

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

A theorem states that every nilpotent linear transformation $f\in\mathrm{End}_F(V)$ has a basis such that the matrix of $f$ with respect to said basis is a Jordan matrix.

Is the converse also true or what would be a counterexample for if a matrix $A$ is a Jordan matrix, then the linear transformation corresponding to $A$ is nilpotent?

I know $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n,\mathrm{End}_F(V)\cong \mathrm{Mat}_n (F)$, but is it enough?

Or in other words, if I take any Jordan matrix and keep multiplying it by itself, does there always exist some integer at which point the power of the matrix becomes the 0 matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no! For example, consider $I$, the identity matrix. It is in Jordan normal form, but it is clearly not nilpotent.

The converse you are looking for is probably that if a matrix is in Jordan normal form **and all its eigenvalues are 0** then it is nilpotent.

Comment: moral of the story: don't overthink and start with the simplest potential counterexample :D Thank you